# how can I make jquery mobile "pagebeforeshow" event fire every time, not just on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page that uses the following code to hide a button when the page is accessed.

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
  $("#apply_btn").hide()
});
```

My problem is that the event only fires when the page is refreshed and not when arriving at the page from somewhere else in the site.

I have tried using the "pageshow" event and the "pageinit" event but it still only fires when the page is refreshed.

Comment: This works for me.  Are you using "rel='external'" in your links as that would stop it working.  The only other thing I can think of is that you have more that one "#apply-btn" spread over your pages.

Comment: One more question. Where are you putting this code? Is it in the head of your document? Or do you have it embedded in the page itself within the page divs?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, Finglish? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

This is the syntax:

```
$( '#yourPage' ).live( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $("#uniqueButtonId").hide();
});
```

Good Luck

Comment: All pages not just one '#yourPage'

Comment: @ShiftyThomas This functionality may only be required on one page. Though I do agree that you could apply it at any level in the dom.

Answer (score 10):

Just to remember that live method has been removed from jQuery 1.9. You should use from now on the **on** method:

```
$( '#yourPage' ).on( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $("#uniqueButtonId").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Strangely enough the short version doesn't work for me:

```
$( '#yourPage' ).on( 'pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $('#uniqueButtonId').hide();
});
```

but I have to use:

```
$(document).on( 'pagebeforeshow' , '#yourPage' ,function(event){
    $('#uniqueButtonId').hide();
});
```

Comment: This is awful. I've spent hours trying to figure out why the short version doesn't work to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){
    $("#apply_btn",context).hide()
});
```