# jQuery mobile scripts not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Here's my situation:

I have two pages. I use this line of code to execute things when a user changes between the two pages. It works, but only when I am loading a page for the first time. If I am returning to a previous page (one that I already visited), it doesn't call this method.

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow',function(){ ... });
```

For example:

I visit page A; the code executes.

I click a link on page A to go to page B; the code executes.

I click a link on page B to go back to page A; the code DOES NOT execute.

I then refresh the page (now on page A), the code does again execute.

Any reason why that would happen?

Comment: The problem has apparently been battled before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549571/how-can-i-make-jquery-mobile-pagebeforeshow-event-fire-every-time-not-just-on

Comment: In that case, your question is a duplicate of the other one you found.

Comment: To some extent, it has, but the other guy did not ask about returning to the same page - he said just pages in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demonstration I made for you to show when events fire for pages in the jQuery Mobile framework (version 1.0): http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/QjtZW/1/

When you navigate to different pages the `pageshow` event **always** fires on the page being shown as you can see in my example.

If you are having issues with `pageshow` firing as it should then you probably have an error or some errors in your code that are blocking code from running. Make sure your error console is clear.

Comment: Thank you! It's pretty clear now that I'm just being an idiot about some other part of my code.