# Binding in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

I'm building an app using Phonegap and I am running into a strange issue where the binding to click events is not working, does anyone know why?

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    $('._jsClick').on('click', function() {
        alert('Hi!')
    });
```

And here is the HTML

```
<button class="_jsClick">Click Here!</button>
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery Mobile to build your mobile app?

Comment: @MattStarkey have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 2):

First you should change click function to:

```
$('._jsClick').on('click', function(event) {
        alert('Hi!')
    });
```

Also you should:

```
$('div:jqmData(role="page")').on('pagebeforeshow', function(){       
    $('._jsClick').on('click', function() {
        alert('Hi!')
    });
});

$('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow', function(){       
        $('._jsClick').on('click', function() {
            alert('Hi!')
        });
    });
```

Not document.ready

Check this link out: [how can I make jquery mobile "pagebeforeshow" event fire every time, not just on refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549571/how-can-i-make-jquery-mobile-pagebeforeshow-event-fire-every-time-not-just-on). The code above will be called when `$.mobile.changePage` is called.

This should look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    $('div:jqmData(role="page")').die('pagebeforeshow');
    $('div:jqmData(role="page")').live('pagebeforeshow', function(){    
       $('._jsClick').off('click'); 
       $('._jsClick').on('click', function() {
        alert('Hi!')
       });
     });
    }
```

Comment: Your pagebeforeshow binding is inncorect. It should be $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){

Comment: If you have multiple pages, you should only use that for that page.

Comment: Check this link out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549571/how-can-i-make-jquery-mobile-pagebeforeshow-event-fire-every-time-not-just-on

Comment: Again, take a look what have you written.

Comment: So I need to have all my binding etc for each different page within a different    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ each time?

Comment: also don't forget to unbind using 'off' on 'pagehide' or to block bound elements from being re-bound when a user visits a page was not removed from the DOM